# Hex to Double converter

Tags: strings, converting, vba

I stumbled on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32814640/1188513) which was asking about a way to convert larger hex values to a positive numeric value:

> ```
> ?Val("&H8000")
>  -32768 
> Val("&HFFFF")
>  -1
> ```

My answer involved iterating the string digits one by one, and computing their respective value into the result:

```
Function ConvertHex(ByVal value As String) As Double

    If Left(value, 2) = "&H" Then
        value = Right(value, Len(value) - 2)
    End If

    Dim result As Double

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = Len(value) To 1 Step -1

        Dim digit As String
        digit = Mid$(value, i, 1)

        result = result + (16 ^ j) * Val("&H" & digit)
        j = j + 1

    Next

    ConvertHex = result

End Function
```

It works, but I can't help thinking I've done something stupidly over-complicated for something that should be pretty simple.

There's a better way, isn't there?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want to accomplish. "Double" usually means a 64-bit floating point number. Yet, your text says you want a "positive numeric value", but then your examples seem to show _signed_ 16-bit integers (usually called a "short"). Furthermore, it would seem that only whole numbers could possibly be represented in the hex string, so the return type should be `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `UShort`, `UInteger`, `ULong`, or `Decimal`.

Comment: @200_success There's only a very limited set of [data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692781.aspx) in VBA. No unsigned types...

Comment: Mat, what's wrong with `Cdbl("&HFFFF")`?

Comment: @Meehow see the update to my answer for why I think `CDbl` is wrong for this scenario.

Comment: @Meehow **that** is exactly what I meant with "I've done something stupidly over-complicated for something that should be pretty simple" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell a string starting with `&H` is a hex literal.

There exists a [number of conversion functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278896.aspx) that can convert an expression to the desired type.

So it should simply be, depending on desired type:

```
Function ConvertHex(ByVal value As String) As Currency
    Dim result As Currency
    result = CCur(value)

    If result < 0 Then
        'Add two times Int32.MaxValue and another 2 for the overflow
        'Because the hex value is apparently parsed as a signed Int64/Int32
        result = result + &H7FFFFFFF + &H7FFFFFFF + 2
    End If

    ConvertHex = result
End Function
```

### Currency vs Double

Maximum accurately representable positive integer value :

- `&H0020000000000000` (9,007,199,254,740,992) for [Double](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264155.aspx) ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format))
- `&H000346DC5D638865` (922,337,203,685,477) for [Currency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264338.aspx)

So why use `Currency` over `Double` when the latter works for a larger range of integers?

`Currency` is *always* accurate. If we overflow a `Currency` value we get an error. If we overflow the maximum representable integer value of a double we get an approximate integer value:

```
Dim doubleMax As Double
Dim doubleAfter As Double
doubleMax = CDbl("&H0020000000000000")
doubleAfter = doubleMax + 1

MsgBox "Double before: " & Format(doubleMax, "#") & vbNewLine & "after: " & Format(doubleAfter, "#")

Dim currencyMax As Currency
Dim currencyAfter As Currency
currencyMax = CCur("&H000346DC5D638865")
currencyAfter = currencyMax + 1

MsgBox "Currency before: " & Format(currencyMax, "#") & vbNewLine & "after: " & Format(currencyAfter, "#")
```

The output of this example is:

```
Double before: 9007199254740990
after: 9007199254740990
```

And then a `run-time error '6': Overflow` which is great if you want to avoid rounding errors. Now MSDN claims `Double` is

> stored as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point number

but if you've read anything about the [IEEE 754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) you should be a bit surprised about the output from the example. The actual maximum is `&H00038D7EA4C68000` (1,000,000,000,000,000).

Comment: Awesome! I've linked to this answer on an edit to my SO answer :-)

Comment: I expanded the bit about `Currency` vs `Double` a little and discovered something interesting.

Comment: how about `doubleMax + doubleMax` throwing an overflow error?

Comment: @Meehow `doubleMax + doubleMax` is only around `1.8E16`. The non integer max value of a `Double` is `1.79769313486232E308` and doubles don't overflow, they go to `INF`.

Comment: @Meehow Just tested it and apparently `Double` in VBA does overflow. But it's still not possible to overflow if the parsed result is an integer. I'm glad I don't have to work with that language.

Comment: The correct, idiomatic way to do this is to use one of the built-in conversion functions, as @Meehow commented on the OP - I don't know what brainfart caused me to even write this function...

Comment: Yup, so long as the values are strictyly less than 32 bit `CLng` is enough.